# Prove that if $\sin(a)=\frac{\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{\cos(b)+\cos(c)}$ then $\triangle ABC$ is right angled

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sin(a)=\frac{\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{\cos(b)+\cos(c)}$$

My attempt:

$$\sin(a)=\frac{\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{\cos(b)+\cos(c)}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{b+c}{2})\cos(\frac{b-c}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{b+c}{2})\cos(\frac{b-c}{2})}=\tan(\frac{b+c}{2})$$

and we know that: $a+b+c=\pi$
so

$$\sin(a)=\frac{\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{\cos(b)+\cos(c)}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{b+c}{2})\cos(\frac{b-c}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{b+c}{2})\cos(\frac{b-c}{2})}=\tan(\frac{b+c}{2})=\tan(\frac{\pi -a}{2})$$

$a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ satisfies the above equation, so if  $\sin(a)=\frac{\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{\cos(b)+\cos(c)}$ then the  triangle ABC is right angled on $a$

So is my attempt right?

Answer (score 0):

You found that $a=\pi/2$ is **a** solution of $\sin(a)=\tan(\frac{\pi-a}{2})$, but you are aiming to prove that it is the **only** solution of said equation for $0<a<\pi$.

**Hint.** Consider the function $f:(0,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin(x)-\tan(\frac{\pi-x}{2})$. Study its zeros and its growth (or plot it and see).

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is incomplete since, as [Fabián Gutiérrez's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4647057/602049) states, you haven't proven that $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is the *unique* solution. One way to do that is to continue from where you left off by using several [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), in particular that

$$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$

to get with $\theta = \pi - a$ in the RHS of your equation that

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi-a}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos(\pi - a)}{\sin(\pi - a)} = \frac{1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}$$

Equating this to the LHS of your equation then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin(a) & = \frac{1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)} \\
\sin^2(a) & = 1+\cos(a) \\
1-\cos^2(a) & = 1+\cos(a) \\
\cos^2(a)+\cos(a) & = 0 \\
\cos(a)(\cos(a)+1) & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

For $0 \lt a \lt \pi$, the first case is $\cos(a) = 0$, which gives just $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$, as you've already found, but the second case of $\cos(a)+1=0 \;\;\to\;\; \cos(a) = -1$ is not possible. Thus, the *only* solution is $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Continuing, if $t = \tan \dfrac{x}{2},$ then

$$\frac{2t}{1+t^2}= \frac{1}{t}, ~ t= \pm 1$$

$$ \frac{x}{2} =\pi/4, 5 \pi/4,.... -\pi/4, - 5 \pi/4.. $$

$$ x =\pi/2, 5 \pi/2,.... -\pi/2, - 5 \pi/2.. $$

Can you express all co-terminal angles by means of  a single formula?

Plot the function. Can you also find which graphical solutions are valid in a triangle?